# Javascript to change colour of items in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list with items that have columns where the user can select Yes or No to certain things, I would like to have it so any instance of Yes is in Green and any instance of No is red

[image]

The issue is I do not know how to write Javascript, once I have the code I can add a link to the JS file in the webpart

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below script in Script Editor Web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Yes')");
$Text.css("background-color", "green");
$Text.css("font-weight", "bold");
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('No')");
$Text.css("background-color", "red");
$Text.css("font-weight", "bold");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, that code has made the whole item red, the columns that are Yes or No are choice fields if that helps?

Comment: yes it would set the entire row red.

Comment: Hey, I would like only the text 'Yes' and 'No' to change colour, not the entire row

Comment: you can modify the jquery and try

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to modify

Comment: try the edited jquery code. i hope it helps.

Comment: great.you can mark my answer as correct one.

Comment: what would I add to make the text bold?

Comment: check with the updated jquery again.

Comment: Hey, I have found a problem when a create a new view, the code does not work at all, the new view I greated is the same as the allitems view apart from one thing, I group by the column 'Service', how do I get the code to work on all views?

Comment: try adding the script again using new webpart. otherwise the script won't work with the filters & groupby, verify the same

Comment: I selected the new view > Edit page and the script block is already there from the allitems view

Comment: yes it takes the page similar to the parent one. try adding a new web part and fresh script for it.

Comment: Added new web part and script but it did not change

Comment: then try removing the groupby time being for crosscheck

Comment: If I remove the Group By is works perfectly

Comment: so it changes the css classes when we apply groupby. need to check

Comment: I fixed this issue, If I select Expanded in the Group By setting in the view it all works

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been <a href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17991/discussion-on-answer-by-hardik-kothari-javascript-to-change-colour-of-items-in-a">moved to chat</a>.

Comment: The script works! However, if you change the view (e.g. sort or turn the pages), the new list elements are no longer displayed in color. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you very much!
Julia

Answer (score -1):

You can just change the 2 lines that have background-color to font-color