# Custom Lists - set row background color in a list depending on a column value

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, client-side-rendering

Starting from this example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd

I would like to set the entire row background color depending on a column value.

Comment: Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317668/how-to-color-code-rows-in-a-sharepoint-list-for-each-page

Comment: you can also refer this : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118500/javascript-to-change-colour-of-items-in-a-list

Answer (score 7):

Below example demonstrates how to customize List View in order to highlight list item rows.

Assume there is a `Tasks` list and depending on status, rows have to be highlighted using the corresponding color.

Template code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var statusColors =  {
          'Not Started' : '#FFF1AD',  
          'In Progress' : '#FFD800',
          'Completed' : '#01DF3A' 
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["Status"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
       }
     }
   }); 

});
```

### How to apply the changes

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Using [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx)
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

### Results

[image]

Comment: thx, but I don't understand what is it: "clienttemplates.js" ?

Comment: Thank you for the script... it works great but if I use Quick Edit to edit the list (task list in my case) I got a type error... property 'Style' is undefined or null reference. I'll try to solve it but if someone has a solution that would be great

Comment: Post Render customization fails if we use sorting or filtering. I works fine on the page load but fails afterwards. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161065/list-web-part-csr-issues-when-sorting-filtering

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by handling `OnPostRender` event. Something like

```
priorityFiledContext.OnPostRender = [
    ApplyRowOverride
];

function ApplyRowOverride(ctx) {
    for(var index = 0; index < ctx.ListData.Row.Length; index++) {
        var item = ctx.ListData.Row[index];
        if(item.Field == "WhateverValue") {
            var row = document.getElementById(GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, item));
            if(row != null) {
                row.style.backgroundcolor = "red";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, but where do I have to write this code? Directly inside my PriorityColorRow.js ? 
(PS: PriorityColorRow.js is the file I use in JS LINK)

Comment: please have a look: http://i.imgur.com/XyBN7QQ.png

Answer (score 0):

replace '`ctx.ListData.Row.Length`' by '`ctx.ListData.Row.length`' in above code